# Reading txt file with number and suming them python

Tags: python, list, text, sum

I have txt file witht the following txt in it:

```
2
4 8 15 16 23 42
1 3 5
6
66 77
77
888
888 77
34
23 234 234
1
32
3
23 23 23 
365
22 12
```

I need a way to read the file and sum all the numbers. 
i have this code for now but not sure what to do next. Thx in advance

```
`lstComplete = []
fichNbr = open("nombres.txt", "r")
lstComplete = fichNbr
somme = 0

for i in lstComplete:
    i = i.split()`
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn them into a list and sum them:

```
with open('nombres.txt', 'r') as f:
    num_list = f.read().split()
    print sum([int(n) for n in num_list])
```

Returns `3227`

Answer (score 0):

Open the file and use `read()` method to get the content and then convert string to int, use `sum()` to get the result:

```
>>> sum(map(int,open('nombres.txt').read().split()))
3227
```

Comment: how does `open` know what file to open? clearly, there is something going on that I don't know.

Comment: @frederick99 just replace `a` with `nombres.txt`, I renamed the file name.

Comment: I thought I missed something. Thank you for letting me know. : )